# Parse database job is not getting all results from http request

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, parse-platform

I have the following code set up as a job in the Parse Cloud Code for my application.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("requestLocations", function (request, response) {Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=29.7030428,-98.1364808&radius=900&types=restaurant&key=AIzaSyCTg0x68Q6lrCAo6-A37zkxge81jDEKpvo'
}).then(function (httpResponse) {
    // Success
    response.success("Success");
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
    var Location = Parse.Object.extend("Locations");

    for (var i = 0; i < parsedData.results.length; i++) {
        var restaurant = new Location();
        var placeId = parsedData.results[i].place_id;
        var name = parsedData.results[i].name;
        var vicinity = parsedData.results[i].vicinity;
        var point = new Parse.GeoPoint({
            latitude: parsedData.results[i].geometry.location.lat,
            longitude: parsedData.results[i].geometry.location.lng
        });

        restaurant.set("placeId", placeId);
        restaurant.set("name", name);
        restaurant.set("vicinity", vicinity);
        restaurant.set("location", point);
        restaurant.save(null, {
            success: function (location) {
                console.log("Object ID: " + location.id);
            },
            error: function (location, error) {
                console.log("Failed to create object, with error code: " + error.message);
            }
        });
    }
}, function (httpResponse) {
    // Error
    response.error('request failed with response code ' + httpResponse)
});});
```

As you can see, this HTTP request should return a total of 14 places. Unfortunately, it will only return 9 places and it would also seem that which 9 are return can change. I am assuming there is a problem with the way my function is put together. Can anyone help me remedy this issue. I would like to return as many places as I want based on the radius of the HTTP request.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http request is done right, with a promise that's fulfilled when the request is complete.  But your then() block tries to create several objects in a loop, not waiting for them all to finish, and failing to call response.success.  Fix it like this...

```
// break it into understandable chunks, too, so, here's a function
// to build a Locations object from the http data

function locationFromResult(result) {
    var Location = Parse.Object.extend("Locations");
    var restaurant = new Location();
    var placeId = result.place_id;
    var name = result.name;
    var vicinity = result.vicinity;
    var point = new Parse.GeoPoint({
        latitude: result.geometry.location.lat,
        longitude: result.geometry.location.lng
    });
    restaurant.set("placeId", placeId);
    restaurant.set("name", name);
    restaurant.set("vicinity", vicinity);
    restaurant.set("location", point);
    return restaurant;
}

Parse.Cloud.job("requestLocations", function (request, response) {
    var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=29.7030428,-98.1364808&radius=900&types=restaurant&key=AIzaSyCTg0x68Q6lrCAo6-A37zkxge81jDEKpvo';
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({url: url}).then(function (httpResponse) {
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
        var locations = parsedData.results.map(function(result) {
            return locationFromResult(result);
        });
        // this is important, saveAll of the new objects before returning
        // this can also be accomplished by saving the objects individually and using Parse.Promise.when()
        return Parse.Object.saveAll(locations);
    }).then(function(result) {
        response.success(JSON.stringify(result));
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: This does not work. I am getting the error thrown. Not sure what the problem is. I did add var the following as the second line in the locationFromResult function but it did not help. Any ideas??

Location = Parse.Object.extend("Locations");

Comment: This is the error log I get with the code as is

E2016-01-06T13:57:54.012Z]v82 Ran job requestLocations with:
  Input: {}
  Result: Error: Job status message must be a string
    at updateJobMessageAndReturn (<anonymous>:1159:7)
    at Object.success (<anonymous>:1213:9)
    at e.<anonymous> (main.js:100:18)
    at e.i (Parse.js:14:27528)
    at e.a.value (Parse.js:14:26888)
    at e.<anonymous> (Parse.js:14:27599)
    at e.i (Parse.js:14:27528)
    at e.a.value (Parse.js:14:26888)
    at e.<anonymous> (Parse.js:14:27599)
    at e.i (Parse.js:14:27528)

Comment: Nevermind, it seems to be working now. Funny, but I got an error last night. Thanks.

Comment: oh.  please see edit.  the job needs to return a string, not an object.  (now i remember learning that via an error when i wrote jobs.  that stringify code was in my code that i pasted in, but i removed thinking it was strange)

Comment: great.  its customary to mark the answer correct if you used it.